# Is it possible to modify CalDAV / CardDav accounts with an app on iOS?

Tags: ios, api, caldav, carddav

I was wondering if there is an API for modifying CalDAV and CardDAV accounts on iOS. I am developing an app and I want to make it possible for the user to simply enable and disable calendar / contact synchronisation without setting it up manually in the iOS settings.
I know that I can bring my own CalDAV / CardDav implementation and synchronize it using EventKit / address book api, but I want to avoid this kind of implementation, because it will be much more difficult and error-prone than using the default CalDav / CardDAV implementation of iOS.

Thank you very much in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do.

1. Create New calDAV/cardDAV account. - A server-side action.
2. Subscribe to an existing calDAV/cardDAV account - Use Settings App on device.
3. Create events/people with a subscribed account - Can do this in you app.

From the Docs:

> Event Kit provides limited access to a user’s Calendar database; it does not include everything that would be desired for implementing a full-featured calendar or reminder app, such as adding attendees or accounts.

Thus, that's a NO for calDAV.

The docs for AddressBook are not as prescriptive, however, knowing the way that Apple likes to give the user ultimate control over anything at the account level I suspect the same if true for cardDAV.

However, there is facility to add calDAV and cardDAV accounts in the Settings App. This would appear to be your only option for **subscribing** to new accounts.

Comment: I want to implement number 2, but AFAIK apple removed the feature to open prefs urls with an app